# How do I check two lists of strings against eachother?

Tags: java, string, compare

Taking a class in OOP Java and since I am completely new to the  language and as of yet unaware of the many tools it has to offer I find myself fumbling in the dark for solutions to simple things, I can hardcode these problems but I feel there is far simpler ways to do this with `java.util`.

Assume I have a list of strings

```
String[] stringOne = {"a","b","c", "potato"};
String[] stringTwo = {"potato", "13"};
```

How do I check how many times any given item in `stringTwo` occurs in `stringOne`? Or vice versa. I would rather not double loop everytime I have this problem (or make a double-loop method).

Right now I get away with using `Collections.frequency()` and only looping once but is there a simpler way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assume I have a list of strings
>
> ```
> String[] stringOne = {"a","b","c", "potato"};
> String[] stringTwo = {"potato", "13"};
> ```

These are "arrays", not "lists".  `Arrays.asList(stringOne)` is a list wrapper for the array referenced by `stringOne`.

> How do I check how many times any given item in stringTwo occurs in stringOne?

```
new HashSet(Arrays.asList(stringOne)).retainAll(Arrays.asList(stringTwo))
```

will give you the set of elements in both.

A similar approach with a [`Bag`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) instead of a set will get you counts.

> ## `retainAll(Collection coll)`
>
> Remove any members of the bag that are not in the given collection, respecting cardinality. That is, if the given collection coll contains n copies of a given object and the bag has m > n copies, then delete m - n copies from the bag. In addition, if e is an object in the bag but `!coll.contains(e)`, then remove `e` and any of its copies.

The notion of equivalence used in the collection classes is that defined by `Object.equals(object)` which `java.lang.String` overrides to compare lexicographically.

If you need the result back in an array, try `myBag.toArray(new String[0])` which dumps the contents to a string.  The argument is explained in the documentation, but in short, its a type-hint that works around Java's broken array variance.